# How to get feedback on unfinished research papers if I don't have any direct contact with people qualified in my field?

Tags: peer-review, feedback, machine-learning

I have a question which can seem a bit unusual.
How can I get feedback on unpublished scientific articles if I have no direct connection with anyone qualified in my field? The fact is that now I am studying for a Bachelor of Computer Science at one of the small provincial universities in Russia, I am researching the field of machine learning (I am developing several new architectures for dialogue modeling and natural language generation).
And my main problem is that I have been studying machine learning and all other necessary disciplines on my own since the age of 15 (now I'm 20), that is, I am an autodidact, I have never received any outside help in learning machine learning. But in my university, there is not a single person at all who has at least some knowledge in this area and who is familiar with modern research in it. Believe me, I was looking for such people, and I have found none, and even one of my projects was rejected at the level of the computer science department as it turned out later because no one understood what it was and what to do with it and no one even asked me for an explanation or gave me an explanation of the reason why it was rejected until I knew this from one of my professors who is a member of the academic council of my university. At the moment, I am locked up in my university with no way to do anything about it (if you want to know, even though my specialization is applied computer science, we have never been taught programming besides of a very blurry theory in survey courses, although I'm a third-year student here, I was forced to learn to program on my own). My only hope is to wait for the end of my studies here and move to another university for a specialized master's program in machine learning (after all, although I study well here and I have never had lower than excellent marks, there is little benefit from it). As you can see, the situation is more than dire. Any help is greatly appreciated accordingly. I am sorry for such a verbose description of my state of affairs. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are you looking for feedback on something you have written, or on papers you found online?

Comment: I am looking for feedback on my own works

Comment: In one thing, Corona is perhaps working in your favour. There are many online workshops now. Pick a small workshop and submit your paper and see how people react. It is not replacing being there and meeting people, but people experiment with different socializing formats nowadays, so you might get some feedback and connections, nonetheless.

Comment: That’s going to be very tough w/o connections which you don’t have. Researchers would usually not just read a paper from an unknown person to provide feedback. If you think it is good enough, consider trying to submit it to a conference, or even journal. If it passes the first round, you’d get reviewers’ feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get feedback on unpublished scientific articles if I have no direct connection with anyone qualified in my field?

**Make contact with those qualified in your field.**

As an undergraduate, without a reputation, don't expect top-professors to be interested. Aim lower. Personally, I'd suggest a top PhD student or a top postdoc. Someone who's work you have studied and are interested by.

**Offer co-authorship.**

Don't ask for help, make a mutually beneficial offer: Many researchers are willing to help (this forum is an example), but, everyone is busy, make an attractive offer when contacting researchers. For instance, you could offer your services to help-out on their work, or you could offer co-authorship of your work (in exchange for guidance), or ... Explain your short- and medium-term goals, e.g., publishing your work, developing your profile, getting a post graduate degree, and pursuing a PhD.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also thought about co-authorship at least because just receiving help is really isn't for me and co-authorship seem to be a much better option.